# Creating datetime object in pandas from out of order dates

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, datetime

I have a dataframe in pandas that looks like this

```
Year Month Month_index Rainfall
1900 Jan   1            4.8
1901 Jan   1            5
.
.
.
1900 Feb   2            3.2
1901 Feb   2            4.3
.
.
```

To use datetime indexing I need to rearrange it to look like -

```
Year Month Month_index Rainfall
1900 Jan   1            4.8
1900 Feb   2            3.2
.
.
1901 Jan   1            5
1901 Feb   2            4.3
.
.
```

Of course there are the full 12 months I'm just showing a little bit for brevity. I'm reasonably new to python so I don't know if there is a command that will do this. 
Thank you in advance!

edit: Here is the code I'm using to get thus far -

```
import csv
#import pyexcel-io as pi
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import dateutil
#Read data from csv file into dataframe
df =pd.read_csv('/Users/Gingeraffe/Documents/University/3rd_year/Bureau_Research/Notebooks/Data/rainfall_SW_WA.csv')

months = df.columns[1:]
#Melt is putting months down a column and the data down another column. 
Problem is ' jan jan jan... feb feb feb..' etc. instead of 'jan feb mar.. etc'
df = pd.melt(df, id_vars='Year', value_vars=months, var_name='Month')
df.insert(2,'Month_index',0)
M = {'Jan':1, 'Feb':2, 'Mar':3, 'Apr':4, 'May':5, 'June':6, 'July':7, 'Aug':8, 'Sep':9, 'Oct':10, 'Nov':11, 'Dec':12}
df.Month_index = df.Month.map(M)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Could you describe your issue in more detail, please? E.g. by adding code, commands or screen shots which describe your problem. Please have also a look to the Help Center, especially for [asking](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [minimal examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a `datetime` series using your three columns, which we can then use to sort:

```
s = pd.to_datetime(
        df[['Year', 'Month']].astype(str).sum(1), format='%Y%b'
)
```

Finally, sort:

```
df.iloc[s.sort_values().index]
```

```
   Year Month Month_index Rainfall
0  1900   Jan           1      4.8
2  1900   Feb           2      3.2
1  1901   Jan           1      5.0
3  1901   Feb           2      4.3
```

Comment: Thank you! All I had to add was df = df.iloc[etc] to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

```
   import pandas as pd  
   d = {'Year' : [1900,1901,1900,1901], 'Month' : ['Jan','Jan','Feb','Feb'] , 'Month_index' : [1,1,2,2], 'Rainfall' : [4.8,5,3.2,4.3]}  
   df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)  
   df = df.sort(['Year','Month_index'])  
   #dataframe <df> should now contain the sorted dataframe
```